# slimscrollbar generates draggable method error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slimscroll

I am trying to use custom scrollbar plugin  SlimScroll. Which is not working .but when I checked the Console there was this error present

```
      Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'draggable' jquery.slimscroll.js:198
```

I have the jquery v 2 file included before the nicescroll reference. what can be wrong..

Comment: Often errors like this are caused by things either loading in the wrong order, or not done at the end / after dom ready.  Without more code its really hard to tell.  Also, does this slimscroll require something else like the jQuery UI library? Draggable I think is part of that.

Comment: Yes Jquery ui is included there

Comment: You're showing just the error you're getting, and none of the code that generates it, I'm not sure what kind of answer you're expecting.  Its impossible to help without a few more details. Please read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: Ok.. Thanks for the help.. You are right it is difficult to solve but showing the page that is cluttered with a lot of other functions and server generated is very difficult to show.. I tried some other plugins and finally `enscroll` worked superfine for me... So finally succeeded after 24 hours of trying :)

Comment: First I tried `NiceScroll` but that was such a `badscroll` plugin and actually it generated the scrollbar positioned absolute relative to the body and that was such disturbing issue..

Comment: Thanks for the "badscroll". No bad as name for a plugin. ;)
To have a scrollbar contained on scrollable div, you have to use a wrapped div.
It's documented, but I think I need to have a better docs.

Comment: Hey!!! @InuYaksa. :)  ..Sorry dear for the comment. Did not want to be rude. just was very angry after continuous failure to make it work. It did not let me guess to put the enclosing relative container.. the div generated by the `NICESCROLL` ;) was attached directly to the body so I had no clue of what to do about that. Then I used the `enscroll` and when I checked the div it generated was below the destination div. So I guess what to do. though both were similar in misbehaving. I must appreciate your efforts. I was angry because I wanted this to work. but that tiny issue was looking very bad

Comment: and yes @InuYaksa documentation makes difference and you must include this issue in capital letters.. Do not let the developer guess. We have a lot of other things to do .. so guessing and reading the whole code from the start ruins the benefit of using reusable code.